# @Keyframes don't move my div

Tags: html, css, css-animations

i'm trying to make my div moves up and down with CSS3, but it doesn't

```
<div class="globo"></div>

@-webkit-keyframes mover {
    0%, 100% { top: 0%;}
    50% { top: 5%; }
}
@-moz-keyframes mover {
    0%, 100% { top: 0%;}
    50% { top: 5%; }
}
@-o-keyframes mover {
    0%, 100% { top: 0%;}
    50% { top: 5%; }
}
@keyframes mover {
    0%, 100% { top: 0%;}
    50% { top: 5%; }
}
.globo{
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 270px;
    background: url('https://lh3.ggpht.com/-hCYXxhc-U4BqD1CBVCARXlp1bPT7ci7pP1Q4NEOzIKpS8zKPfyCCQF5xjEVUf4vGrJ2=w300');
    -webkit-animation: mover 5s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
     -moz-animation:    mover 5s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
     -o-animation:      mover 5s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation:         mover 5s infinite;
}
```

you can see my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/LGMv7/1/

Comment: Since you are using keyframes, is there a reason you're not using CSS transforms for your animations, as opposed to animating position? You'll get better performance using something like translate3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your .globo

```
position: absolute;


.globo{
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 270px;
    background: url('https://lh3.ggpht.com/-hCYXxhc-U4BqD1CBVCARXlp1bPT7ci7pP1Q4NEOzIKpS8zKPfyCCQF5xjEVUf4vGrJ2=w300');
    -webkit-animation: mover 5s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
     -moz-animation:    mover 5s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
     -o-animation:      mover 5s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation:         mover 5s infinite;
}
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LGMv7/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

your div Need ! position absolute! try!

or apply  the property transform, whit transform you div.globo not need position abosolute!