# keyframes doesn't move my div block

Tags: html, css, css-animations

after reseraching and finding this post: [@Keyframes don't move my div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002118/keyframes-dont-move-my-div)

and trying to figure out the problem based on that post, I still couldn't figure out why my keyframes just refuses to move my div block. I am still very new to html and css.

the image in the code is supposed to be the logo but I just randomly inserted an image as a placeholder for now.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you so much!

```css
@keyframes move {
 0% { top: 0%; opacity: 0;}
    100% { top: 50%; opacity: 1;}
 
}

a#btn_niche {
 margin: auto;
 font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 color: #5A3E2E;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 letter-spacing: 0.07em;
 font-size: 2.1em;
}

.niche_logo {
 margin: auto;
}

.logoblock:hover {
 animation: mymove 3s ease-out forwards;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="button_container">
 <a href="http://www.uncommonobjects.com/" target="_blank" id="btn_niche"><div class="logoblock"><img class="niche_logo" src="https://cbsstlouis.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/niche_taste_exterior.jpg" width=7%></div> niche</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change mymove to move on animation property.
also you can use `margin-top` instead of `top` property.
and you should put animation on `niche_logo` to make it work correctly. if you use your animation on `logoblock` class since it moves down hover your mouse pointer wont be on your element and it would jump back up.

```css
@keyframes move {
 0% { margin-top: 0; opacity: 0;}
    100% { margin-top: 50%; opacity: 1;}
 
}

a#btn_niche {
 margin: auto;
 font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 color: #5A3E2E;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 letter-spacing: 0.07em;
 font-size: 2.1em;
}

.niche_logo {
 margin: auto;
}

.niche_logo:hover {
 animation: move 3s ease-out forwards; /*change my move to move*/
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="button_container">
 <a href="http://www.uncommonobjects.com/" target="_blank" id="btn_niche"><div class="logoblock"><img class="niche_logo" src="https://cbsstlouis.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/niche_taste_exterior.jpg" width=7%></div> niche</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I just have one more question: I wanted it to only move the logoblock and not the text as in this case both the logo and the text moves. Is there  way to fix the text's position and only let the image come down and stay there upon hovering?

Comment: @JessicaFan that is  completely different question. please look at this code: https://codepen.io/alireza-mh/pen/pwgMzQ , i tried to make what you want but i think i should rewrite most part of you code. read about css positioning :https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: @JessicaFan Try this code https://codepen.io/alireza-mh/pen/pwgMzQ again. i made some changes

Comment: @JessicaFan you'r welcome , you can up vote the answer as well. :)